# Using cloudinary with App-Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, cloudinary

How do I use cloudinary with App engine?

Particularly, there is a whole git project about how to use cloudinary with Parse. Following the instructions in the example project I am able to setup parse and then query parse for uploadParams

```
Map<String,String> 
uploadParams= ParseCloud.callFunction(PARSE_SIGN_CLOUD_FUNCTION, new HashMap<String, String>(0));
```

which I then use to upload videos to cloudinary

```
uploadParams.put("resource_type", "video"); 
Map cloudinaryResult=cloudinary.uploader().upload(new File(videoPathString), uploadParams);
```

Any help on using Cloudinary with App-engine? I am using endpoints, it that matters.

Comment: I am not looking for a git project, just some steps on how to accomplish this with App-Engine. At the end of the day, all I need is a `cloudinary Identifier` or ` cloudinary url` to save to my app engine datastore.

Comment: Or does app engine work better with something other than cloudinary?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Cloudinary Google App Engine sample project](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java/tree/master/samples/photo_album_gae).

In particular, [PhotoUpload.java, lines 14-20](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java/blob/master/samples/photo_album/src/main/java/cloudinary/models/PhotoUpload.java#L14-L20) demonstrates how to obtaining the resource URL:

```
return Singleton.getCloudinary().url()
    .resourceType(resourceType)
    .type(type)
    .format(format)
    .version(version)
    .generate(publicId);
```